# Technical explanation for an obvious discontinuity

Tags: calculus, continuity

Say $f(x)= \frac{1}{x^2-17x+66}$, and you're supposed to find where $f(\frac{2}{x-2})$ is discontinuous. It's pretty clear that, apart from the points you get from the roots of the binomial in the denominator, the other required point would be $x=2$, since $f(\frac{2}{x-2})$ becomes $f(\frac{2}{0})$.

Is there a technical explanation for this, though? Because when you substitute $x$ for $\frac{2}{x-2}$ in the original expression for $f(x)$, the result is $\frac{(x-2)^2}{4-34(x-2)+66(x-2)^2}$. Evaluating this with $2$ for $x$ gives the final answer $0$, not an undefined value.

Why is this way of looking at it incorrect?

Comment: The discontinuity at $x=2$ of $f(\frac{2}{x-2})$ a discontinuity of the input, rather than a discontinuity of $f$ specifically. $\frac{2}{0}$, being undefined, is not in the domain of $f$, so *technically* $f$ is discontinuous at undefined values?

Comment: Kinda makes sense, but how can a function be discontinuous at a point which isn't even in its domain?

Comment: Well, it's definitely not *continuous* at a point that isn't even in it's domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $\frac 2 {x-2}$ for $x$ into the expression for $f(x)$ does not yield $\frac{(x-2)^2}{4-34(x-2)+66(x-2)^2}$, it yields
$$
\frac{1}{\left(\frac 2 {x-2}\right)^2-17\cdot\frac 2 {x-2}+66},
$$
which is still undefined for $x=2$. The simplification you did yields a term that can then be evaluated at $x=2$, but the defining term can't. While this leaves $x=2$ a value for which $f\left(\frac 2 {x-2}\right)$ is not defined, it does show that this gap in the domain can be closed: there is a unique continuous extension of $f\left(\frac 2 {x-2}\right)$ at $x=2$. This is an example of a [removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(mathematics)#Real_analysis).

An easier example would be $g(x) = \frac{x}{x}$, which has maximal domain $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, since $\frac 0 0$ is not defined. However, both one sided limits $\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac x x$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac x x$ exist and are equal to $1$. Hence $\hat g(x)=1$ is the unique continuous extension of $g$ to all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The first part wraps it up nicely; the rest is a bit too advanced, haha. Would the TL;DR be "Your simplification is wrong because you cross multiplied in the denominator, and that isn't defined for fractions with zero at the bottom"?

Comment: Your simplification is correct for all $x\neq 2$. For $x=2$ you multiplied nominator and denominator of an already undefined expression by $0$. This is just like $\frac x x = 1$ being true only for all $x\neq 0$, since otherwise the LHS isn't even defined.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: In other words, in the case of fractions, you have to keep track of what values of $x$ would cause the denominator to be zero before, during, and after the process of simplification. These will remain discontinuities.